# Binary PowerShell Core cmdlet using SimpleInjector results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-standard, simple-injector, powershell-core

## The Question

I'm trying to create a PowerShell Core binary cmdlet library that uses SimpleInjector, but cannot figure out why it's resulting in a `FileNotFoundException` when debugging it with Visual Studio.

## Details

I've created a super simple PowerShell cmdlet library in Visual Studio, targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and using the [`PowerShellStandard.Library`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library) package (v5.1.0-RC1). [You can view/clone it here](https://github.com/refactorsaurusrex/SimpleInjectorPowerShellCoreIssue). It contains the following cmdlet:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using SimpleInjector;

[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "SimpleInjectorDependency")]
public class TestSimpleInjectorDependencyCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        WriteObject("Success!");
    }
}
```

The result is a `FileNotFoundException`:

[image: simple-injector]

This *seems* specific to SimpleInjector because doing the same thing with, for example, json.net runs without a problem:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using SimpleInjector;

[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "JsonDotNetDependency")]
public class TestJsonDotNetDependencyCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var j = new JObject();
        WriteObject("Success!");
    }
}
```

[image: json.net]

I really don't understand what is happening here. I'm not even sure if this is truly specific to SimpleInjector or if there are other factors at play. If anyone can enlighten me, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: This ia typically a build or NuGet problem, but, to be honest, I'm unsure whether I would ever use a DI Container for building my PowerShell commandlets. They are typically small enough to use Pure DI.

Comment: Regardless of whether the approach is a good idea or not, I'd still like to understand what is happening. Call it a matter of pure curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the *best* solution, but I did finally come up with a resolution to my problem:

First, I added a post-build event: `dotnet publish --no-build`.

[image]

Second, in the project's "Debug" tab, I changed the "Application arguments" to import my cmdlet module from the `\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\publish\` directory, instead of from `\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\`. So, instead of this:

`-NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Import-Module .\MyNetStandardProject.dll"`

I used this:

`-NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Import-Module .\publish\MyNetStandardProject.dll"`

As shown here:

[image: debug settings]

Once I did that, I was able to run the `Test-SimpleInjectorDependency` cmdlet described in my question without error.

Comment: Thanks - I got a similar problem and solved it with your solution - did you get into a state where the breakpoints (within the Cmdlet code) in VS were being ignored?

Comment: Not in this particular situation, no. But when that's happened to me in the past, usually it's because I loaded old binaries. Make sure you've loaded the most recently compiled binaries and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok for some reason, I had to launch powershell from command line, then use 'Attach to Process' and pick powershell.  If I ran the debugger from right clicking the .net standard library and clicking Debug, it would not hit the breakpoint (tried on VS 2017 and 2019).   I only see one other person online having this issue.

Comment: I noticed what's wrong, I was using 'powershell.exe' (the Windows version), not Powershell 6, the 'core' version

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Glad you figured it out!